# Pod has more resources than expected

Tags: kubernetes

I created a Pod (see config below) on k8s (AKS, k8s version 1.19.7) with `cpu="6"` and `memory=20G`. So I expected the Pod to have 6 cores on the CPU as I read on the [k8s docu](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/)

> One cpu, in Kubernetes, is equivalent to 1 vCPU/Core for cloud
> providers

When I check `lscpu` on the container, I get

```
root@user-ubuntu:/# lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          16                                  <-- 2x 8 hyperthreading cores?
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-15
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              8                               <-- expected 6
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           85
Model name:                      Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8168 CPU @ 2.70GHz
```

Also, the memory seems to be 32G instead of 20G

```
root@user-ubuntu:/# vmstat -s -S M
        32114 M total memory
```

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: user-ubuntu
spec:
  containers:
  - name: user-ubuntu
    image: ubuntu:latest
    command: ["/bin/sleep", "3650d"]
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: "6"
        memory: 20G
      limits:
        cpu: "6"
        memory: 20G
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/mnt/azure"
      name: volume
  restartPolicy: Always
  volumes:
    - name: volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: pvc-user-default
```

Comment: Those values will be restricted by cgroup, but it does not really isolate you from inspecting the host resources. You can see that the host machine has 16 CPUs and 32Gb of memory, but your container won't be allowed to use more than 6 cpus and 20Gb of ram correspondingly.

Comment: I'd expect your process to be throttled by the kernel scheduler to use not more than 6 CPU-seconds per second, but to otherwise be able to see all of the physical hardware, and to be scheduled for time slices on any and all physical cores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lscpu` command displays kernel resoures, in particular, from `/proc/cpuinfo` (see [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lscpu)). Now, all the containers running on host system (which can be a physical machine or a VM) share the same kernel (this is the distinguishing feature of containers vs. VMs). Thus, the information you get from `lscpu` corresponds to the underlying host and not the container.

Here's a list of references where this issue is discussed:

- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=25213368
- https://github.com/lxc/lxcfs/issues/181
- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/92904
- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/53706

Your container is however restricted by a [cgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) to the resource usage you defined in the Pod definition. So, even though `lscpu` displays 16 cores, your container can still only use 6 of them. The same applies for the memory.